# Is there any way to remove "Inspect Element" from Chrome's right click context menu?

Tags: google-chrome, context-menu, firebug

Is there any way to remove "Inspect Element" from chrome's right click context menu?

I've tried googling this, but I get a lot of Firefox results and a lot of people looking to do other things with "Inspect Element".

I just want it gone from the right click menu because I've been using Firebug for a while, I'm happy with it, and I hate accidentally clicking the wrong Inspect option.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, also I frequently hit F12 on accident which also brings up the inspect element page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/)
2. Search the whole code base for `spect element`.
3. Check out the references to this string, make sure they don't add it to a menu.
4. Compile your version of Chromium, this will make a version without that menu entry.

Or, if you don't want to go through this for a small change; you'll grow out of the habit over time instead.

Personally, I learned to use that instead as Firebug Lite is quite lacking and I won't go to bloated Firefox.

<sub>Lacking as in "access restrictions", bloated as in "Extensive testing shows that Firefox is noticeably slower, both on a clean profile.".</sub>

Comment: That seems to be the only option. Customization isn't exactly Chrome's strong suit.

Comment: I was afraid it might come down to that. Thanks anyway then.